# Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ResolutionFailedException - Only occurring in 64bit application

Tags: c#, unity-container, prism

I'm experiencing a strange error whereby my application runs fine in 32bit, but fails in 64bit. The project builds successfully as a 64bit project. However, when I run the application, nothing is displayed and the thread is suspended after a few seconds. On further investigation through the Event Viewer, I discovered the error as follows:

```
    Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ResolutionFailedException
Stack:
   at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.DoBuildUp(System.Type, System.Object, System.String, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ResolverOverride>)
   at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.Resolve(System.Type, System.String, Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ResolverOverride[])
   at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainerExtensions.Resolve[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]](Microsoft.Practices.Unity.IUnityContainer, Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ResolverOverride[])
   at MyApp.Prism.Bootstrapper.CreateShell()
```

[more of the stack follows, not shown here]

As mentioned, this only occurs in the 64bit version of the application. My Bootstrapper class looks as follows:

```
public class Bootstrapper : UnityBootstrapper
    {
        protected override System.Windows.DependencyObject CreateShell()
        {
            return Container.Resolve<Shell>();
        }        

        protected override void InitializeShell()
        {
            base.InitializeShell();

            App.Current.MainWindow = (Window)Shell;
            App.Current.MainWindow.Show();
        }

        protected override Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Modularity.IModuleCatalog CreateModuleCatalog()
        {
            ModuleCatalog catalog = new ModuleCatalog();
            return catalog;
        }

        protected override Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Regions.RegionAdapterMappings ConfigureRegionAdapterMappings()
        {
            RegionAdapterMappings mappings = base.ConfigureRegionAdapterMappings();
            mappings.RegisterMapping(typeof(TabGroupPane), Container.Resolve<TabGroupPaneRegionAdapter>());
            return mappings;
        }
    }
```

What is it that I'm missing?

Comment: Try using try-catch in `CreateShell` and `ConfigureRegionAdapterMappings` and look into inner exception. There could be some additional info for this problem.